# Exclude a single module from a Drush update?

Tags: drush

Is there a way to exclude a module from a Drush update so it can be ignored when running eg 'drush up' ?

I ask because Rules 2.8 is causing problems with Drupal Commerce but it would be great if everything else could still be updated with Drush.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
drush pm-update --lock=modulename
```

There is a post here about it: http://blog.wassill.eu/en/blog/short-excludes-modules-drush-update-09-04-2013