# How can I tell Drupal to skip a failed DB update instruction?

Tags: database, updating

when updating from 8.5.x to 8.6.1, an error happened when running one of the database update instructions. More precisely, the error occurs when Drupal is trying to run function `taxonomy_update_8502()`.

This is the error message I get.

> Update #8502
>   Failed: Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydbname.taxonomy_term_hierarchy' doesn't exist: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression FROM (SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {taxonomy_term_hierarchy} taxonomy_term_hierarchy) subquery; Array()` in `taxonomy_update_8502()` (line 37 of /var/www/html/core/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.install).

I can see why the error is happening. The *taxonomy_term_hierarchy* table doesn't exist any longer in the database and this database update is trying to remove it. Reading about [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs/issues/2996221), I found that Drupal 8.6.x moves data from the old table (*taxonomy_term_hierarchy*) into the new table (*taxonomy_term__parent*).

Something must have halted the database update, and Drupal thinks the update function hasn't executed, but I can see on the new *taxonomy_term__parent* table is there. Perfect! So I still have pending updates I need to run, and now I need `taxonomy_update_8502()` to get out of my way.

How can I tell Drupal to forget that database update, or just ignore it, or even artificially consider it has ran already? Is there something I can do in that regard, like definitely skipping a database update?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146129/exclude-a-single-module-from-a-drush-update) , may use `drush pm-update --lock=taxonomy` .

Comment: Uhmmm, thank you for sharing this hint. I will probably be  able to try this fix tomorrow. Do you know if this instruction will permanently 'forget' about the failed update, or will it keep it in standby waiting for the next time I have to run a database update? If the latter is the case, I will have to run updates all the time with this `--lock` instruction and I will definitely have problems when the Taxonomy module issues a new database update.

Comment: If the issue comes from something odd from your database, you should always run the update with `--lock` , other wise if the issue comes from `Taxonomy Module` in the  `8.6.1` version, you should open an issue to the `Taxonomy` issue queue, after the issue fixed and committed you won't need `--look`  anymore, did you try to update  from `8.5.x` to `8.6.1` in fresh install to see if the issue from your db or in the taxonomy module?

Comment: The question addressed database updates but the --lock suggestion only works for module updates.